# Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, unix, segmentation-fault, fasta

I am using python 2.4.4 (old machine, can't do anything about it) on a UNIX machine. I am extremely new to python/programming and have never used a UNIX machine before. This is what I am trying to do:

1. extract a single sequence from a FASTA file (proteins + nucleotides) to a temporary text file.
2. Give this temporary file to a program called 'threader'
3. Append the output from threader (called tempresult.out) to a file called results.out
4. Remove the temporary file.
5. Remove the tempresult.out file.
6. Repeat using the next FASTA sequence.

Here is my code so far:

```
import os
from itertools import groupby

input_file = open('controls.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('results.out', 'a')

def fasta_parser(fasta_name):
input = fasta_name
parse = (x[1] for x in groupby(input, lambda line: line[0] == ">"))
for header in parse:
    header = header.next()[0:].strip()
    seq = "\n".join(s.strip() for s in parse.next())
    yield (header, '\n', seq)

parsedfile = fasta_parser(input_file)

mylist = list(parsedfile)

index = 0

while index < len(mylist): 
    temp_file = open('temp.txt', 'a+')
    temp_file.write(' '.join(mylist[index]))    
    os.system('threader' + ' temp.txt' + ' tempresult.out' + ' structures.txt')
    os.remove('temp.txt')
    f = open('tempresult.out', 'r')
    data = str(f.read())
    output_file.write(data)   
    os.remove('tempresult.out')
    index +=1


output_file.close()
temp_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

When I run this script I get the error 'Segmentation Fault'. From what I gather this is to do with me messing with memory I shouldn't be messing with (???). I assume it is something to do with the temporary files but I have no idea how I would get around this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Update 1:
Threader works fine when I give it the same sequence multiple times like this:

```
import os


input_file = open('control.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('results.out', 'a')

x=0

while x<3:    
    os.system('threader' + ' control.txt' + ' tempresult.out' + ' structures.txt')
    f = open('tempresult.out', 'r')  
    data = str(f.read())
    output_file.write(data)    
    os.remove('result.out')
    x += 1


output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

Update 2: In the event that someone else gets this error. I forgot to close temp.txt before invoking the threader program.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're partially right - a segmentation violation is caused by your program trying to access memory it's not supposed to access. But you're probably also partially wrong - the error is probably in the code you haven't shown us (i.e. your fasta_parser routine). Please [edit] your question and add the code for fasta_parser, as well.

Comment: OT but you have extra (they don't matter) parens around tempfile.write(..) and parsedfile = (fasta...).  You don't need them, but @FrankSchmitt is right about needing to see fasta_parser()

Comment: Done :) It is a bit of a frankenstein hack job but it works. Any suggestions to improve it would be fantastic! Also, I would use 'biopython' but the machine I am using doesn't have it and I don't have permission to install it. Thanks for the note on the parentheses too!

Comment: @FrankSchmitt done

Comment: More questions :-) What is `threader`? Do you still get the error if you comment out the `os.system()` call?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt -  Threader is a piece of protein structure prediction software. It uses a known scaffold (structures.txt) to predict the likely structure of a given target sequence (temp.txt). It gives an output (tempresult.out). My aim is to give it several target sequences and append all of the output results into one file. When I delete the os.system call I get the error: 'No such file or directory: 'tempresult.out'. This is because threader creates the tempresult.out file.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - When I remove the os.system() call and change f = open('tempresult.out', 'r') to open('tempresult.out', 'a+') I get no error

Comment: This looks like the SIGSEGV is caused by the `threader` executable. To verify this, call threader from the command line with your sample data - you should again get the SIGSEGV. If that's the case, you'll have to contact the developers of `threader` regarding this (or ask in a user group etc.).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - Threader works fine when called from the command line.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - threader works fine also when I give it the same sequence multiple times such as in my update 1 above. So it seems that it is the creation and deletion of the 'temp.txt' which is the problem?

Comment: How can pure Python cause a segfault? I've never run into such a situation. This probably has something to do with the command you're calling with `os.system`

Comment: @ForceBru - I worked it out! My mistake was not closing the temp.txt before invoking threader.